# Has anybody successfully added NFHL (National Flood Hazard Layer) to ArcGIS for flex?

Tags: arcgis-server, cartography, arcgis-flex-api

I keep getting the following error when I add the map service to my application:

apServer layer failed to load: Fault code: Channel.Security.Error

Fault info: Security error accessing url

Fault details: Destination: DefaultHTTP

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this the service you are referring to?
"https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer"

I was trying to use it in the javascript API and found some errors that led me to believe that the service runs in an old (unpatched) version of ArcGIS Server. I don't know if that is true or not but I found reference to the problem on an ESRI page describing a service pack. It wasn't a Security Error that I got though (sorry I don't remember the specifics).

Comment: Yes it is that service.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting to their http (instead of https).

Their crossdomain.xml file doesn't allow connections from a http server to their https server.  You can either connect https-to-https, or http-to-http, but not http-to-https (based on https://hazards.fema.gov/crossdomain.xml).

Using http://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer works fine for me in both Flex and Javascript apps.

Answer (score 0):

In internet properties under advanced the Use TLS 1.2 should be checked.